# Display: block. A vertical version?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This ones kinda silly. Whats the best way to simulate display:block but vertical. You know how display:block refuses to let a neighboring component left/right. What is the best "display:" to refuse top/bottom neighbors.

Comment: There isn't a property for that. HTML documents are designed to flow vertically and move/wrap content to a new line as width caps out. You should consider the reason as to why you want to do something like this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a vertical writing mode to the parent, and restore the horizontal mode in the children.

```css
body {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}
div {
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Foo</div>
<div>Bar</div>
<div>Baz</div>
```

This way blocks won't be allowed to stack vertically, just like they can't horizontally in horizontal mode. But if you have some inline-blocks, they may stack vertically just like they can horizontally in horizontal mode.

Answer (score 2):

`display : flex;` might do

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body > * {
  padding: 1em;
  background: gray;
  margin: 1rem;
}
h2 {
  margin: auto 1rem;
}
hr {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1> title</h1>
<h2>subtitle <br/> to center ?</h2>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div>
  <h3>sub sub title</h3>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<h1> title</h1>
<h2>subtitle</h2>
<p>paragraph</p>
<div>
  <h3>sub sub title</h3>
  <p>paragraph</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qavwpG